# Access Violation while loading multiple Timages in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am getting an access violation when I try to load the images. The error occurs when I try to load from file. Is there any way around this?

Here is the code:

```
Public
  img: array of TImage;

...

SetLength(img, 50);

for I := 0 to 50 - 1 do
begin
  img[I] := TImage.Create(panels[I]);
  img[I].parent := panels[I];
  img[I].Width := 80;
  img[I].Height := 80;
  img[I].left := 0;
  img[I].top := 0;
  img[I].Stretch := true;
  img[I].Free;
  img[I].Picture.LoadFromFile('./img1.bmp');
end;
```

I want to create multiple images with different picture that I get from a URL. But I need to get this working with one image first.

Comment: `img[I].Free;` ??????

Comment: Instead of _FOR I:=0 TO 50-1_ you should use the built-in functions _LOW_ and _HIGH_, as in _FOR I:=LOW(img) TO HIGH(img)_. This way, you don't need to change anything if you decide to change the length of the array in the _SetLength_ call.

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing image objects and adding them in a list, but then you call `img[I].Free` which destroys that image object. When you access it in the next line trying to load it, you will be using invalid object and this is why your application crashes.

Just remove that line.

You are constructing `TImage` controls with owner control - panel - that panel as their owner will automatically cleanup those image controls when the panel itself is destroyed, so you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

However, if for some reason you want to clear and remove images you store in the array, you will have to loop through the array and then call `img[I].Free`. Of course, after you do that you shouldn't access those images. Commonly in such scenarios you should set image reference to `nil`, to signal your other code there is no valid image in the array. Another way would be setting length of array to 0.

```
for I := 0 to 50 - 1 do
  begin
    img[I].Free;
    img[I] := nil;
  end;
```

or

```
for I := 0 to 50 - 1 do
  begin
    img[I].Free;
  end;    
SetLength(img, 0);
```

Comment: I removed the .Free but im still getting the error.

Comment: That is probably due to loading file which does not exist in the path. You cannot use relative path, you should use absolute path.